# Azure DevOps MSAL authentication in vb

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, azure-ad-msal

I'm developing an application to help users scrape information off DevOps, and so rather than hard coding in my PAT token I'm' trying to use the MSAL library to let them login via the windows credential authentication window.

I'm following along with the Microsoft example here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/DualSupportClientSample

Now when I build and run the code in c#, it works fine, no problems. However my application is in vb, and when I run my translated vb code (below) the authentication window won't trigger and instead I get a permission denied error (System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com.)

What am I doing wrong here? Translating the entire app into vb is not really an option since this is an extension of an existing vb app which is already quite large. Thanks in advance.

```vb
'replacing organization with the relevant organization
Dim connection As VssConnection = New VssConnection(New Uri("https://dev.azure.com/organization"), New VssClientCredentials())
Dim witClient As WorkItemTrackingHttpClient = connection.GetClient(Of WorkItemTrackingHttpClient)()
Dim query As Wiql = New Wiql() With {
    .Query = "SELECT [Id], [Title], [State] FROM workitems WHERE [Work Item Type] = 'Bug' AND [Assigned To] = @Me"
    }
Dim queryResults As WorkItemQueryResult = witClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(query).Result
```